# matplotlib: how to refresh figure.canvas

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib

I can't understand how to refresh FigureCanvasWxAgg instance. Here is the example:

```
import wx
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MainFrame(wx.Frame): 
    def __init__(self): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.NewId(), "Main") 
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(1,2))
        self.axe = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.figurecanvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        self.buttonPlot = wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Plot")
        self.buttonClear = wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Clear")

        self.sizer.Add(self.figurecanvas, proportion=1, border=5, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.buttonPlot, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.buttonClear, proportion=0, border=2, flag=wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        self.figurecanvas.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.on_dclick)
        self.buttonPlot.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button_plot)
        self.buttonClear.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button_clear)

        self.subframe_opened = False

    def on_dclick(self, evt):
        self.subframe = SubFrame(self, self.figure)
        self.subframe.Show(True)
        self.subframe_opened = True

    def on_button_plot(self, evt):
        self.axe.plot(range(10), color='green')
        self.figurecanvas.draw()

    def on_button_clear(self, evt):
        if self.subframe_opened:
            self.subframe.Close()
        self.figure.set_canvas(self.figurecanvas)
        self.axe.clear()
        self.figurecanvas.draw()


class SubFrame(wx.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent, figure): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.NewId(), "Sub")
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.figurecanvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, figure)
        self.sizer.Add(self.figurecanvas, proportion=1, border=5, flag=wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close)

    def on_close(self, evt):
        self.GetParent().subframe_opened = False
        evt.Skip()



class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MainFrame()
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

I'm interested in the following sequence of operations:

- run a script
- resize the main frame
- press Plot button
- double click on plot
- press Clear button

Now I get a mess on main frame plot. If I resize the frame it redraws properly. My question is what should I add to my code to do that without resizing?

By a "mess" I mean something like this:

http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/5407/mess.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Alex, I'm not sure what you are asking, what do you mean by a "mess"?  I tried your code and I don't see any problems.  Main frame resizes ok, button draws plot, double-click creates a new frame showing the same figure canvas as the main, clear button clears the plot and closes the sub-frame.

Comment: Hmm.. that's weird, I added the picture with the state after Clear.

Comment: I originally tried in on Linux, under Windows I can reproduce your picture.  It's because you are sharing your figure object between the two wxFrames (probably not a good idea).  If no one bets me to it, I'll take a closer look this evening.

Comment: @Mark, Thank you, sharing the figure is my idea for increasing performance since I wouldn't like to create a new plot and draw it another time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I don't think that the figure canvas refresh is your problem, in fact I think it's doing exactly what it's supposed to (redrawing itself based on it's last state [ie as it was in your subplot]).  I think your problem is more that the wxFrame is not refreshing.

The easiest way to fix that would be to make it resize itself on your "Clear" event.  Something like:

```
def on_button_clear(self, evt):
    if self.subframe_opened:
        self.subframe.Close()
    self.figure.set_canvas(self.figurecanvas)
    self.axe.clear()
    self.figurecanvas.draw()  
    self.SetSize((self.Size[0],self.figurecanvas.Size[1]))
```

The set size would cause the frame and all the controls it contains to be redrawn.

That said, I think sharing your figure between the two figurecanvas is dangerous.  I was able to produce some serious errors by clicking/resizing things in different combinations.  On occasion your figure would be garbage collected when the subframe was closed, making it unavailable to your main frame.

Comment: Resizing wouldn't be user-friendly in my case, but thanks, it seems like the best I can do is to avoid sharing the figure.

Comment: `self.axe.clear()` is very slow! I my app, I need to plot for many time, `self.axe.clear()` will hang my app for 0.5s :(