# matplotlib and pyqt5 - refresh with button handle

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am a newbie in Python programming, I have started recently.
I am also discovering OOP, I was mostly programming embedded software based on ASM and C languages. 
I have a small project where I need to read a file, get the data and "clean" them. These data are plot on a figure in Cartesian and in Polar coordinate. So far I achieved to grab examples of code here and there and to make the interface with pyQt5 and integrate both matplotlib canvases on them.

I have created a button called 'clean' when pressed it creates an event which is working, which clean the data but so far I didn't achieve to refresh the canvasses with the cleaned data.

I think that I got lost with the classes, functions and variables in the OOP of the pyQt integration.

Can somebody help me to see the main structure of the program and to pooint out my issue?
I also know that my python code is not that 'clean' and that I am not using the best of it and I verbose quite a lot... This come from C background.

See below code, I have removed the data treatment from the file. I need to plot the following list of list called *LDTvalue[][]*, I have two graph on one plot which is the list of *LDTvalue[0] and LDTvalue[6]*:

I figure out that I cannot change any widget when calling the button even clicked. The window title change but not the widgets label for example. So this is where I have a strong suspicion of messing up with the classes and objects functions.

#### ### UPDATE, I have copied the complete code, a bit dirty, but was a first try :) ###

```
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from numpy import arange, sin, cos, pi, radians
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


LDTheader = {'Company': 'xxx','Type_ind': 0,'Symmetry': 0, 'Mc': 0, 'Dc': 0 , 'Ng': 0, 'Dg': 0}
LDTline = list()
LDTCplane = list()
LDTCvalue = list()
LDTvalue = list()
LDTvalue2 = list()

LDTtemplist = list()

LDTfile = open('01.ldt')
for line in LDTfile :
    LDTline.append(line.strip())

LDTheader['Company'] = LDTline[0];
LDTheader['Type_ind'] = LDTline[1];
LDTheader['Symmetry'] = LDTline[2];


LDTheader['Mc'] = int(LDTline[3]);
LDTheader['Dc'] = float(LDTline[4]);
LDTheader['Ng'] = int(LDTline[5]);
LDTheader['Dg'] = float(LDTline[6]);

print("Company name:", LDTheader['Company'])
print("Type indicator:", LDTheader['Type_ind'])
print("Symmetry:", LDTheader['Symmetry'])

print("Mc:", LDTheader['Mc'])
print("Dc", LDTheader['Dc'])
print("Ng:", LDTheader['Ng'])
print("Dg:", LDTheader['Dg'])

if LDTheader['Type_ind'] == '1' :
    print('1 - point source with symmetry about the vertical axis')
elif LDTheader['Type_ind'] == '2' :
    print('2 - linear luminaire')
elif LDTheader['Type_ind'] == '3' :
    print('3 - point source with any other symmetry')
else: print('Error in source type indicator!')

if LDTheader['Symmetry'] == '0' :
    print('0 - no symmetry')
elif LDTheader['Symmetry'] == '1' :
    print('1 - symmetry about the vertical axis')
elif LDTheader['Symmetry'] == '2' :
    print('2- symmetry to plane C0-C180')
elif LDTheader['Symmetry'] == '3' :
    print('3- symmetry to plane C90-C270')
elif LDTheader['Symmetry'] == '4' :
    print('4- symmetry to plane C0-C180 and to plane C90-C270')
else: print('Error in symmetry paramater!')

for i in range(42,42+LDTheader['Mc']) :
    LDTCplane.append(LDTline[i])

for i in range(42+LDTheader['Mc'],42+LDTheader['Mc']+LDTheader['Ng']) :
    LDTCvalue.append(float(LDTline[i]))


#Separate all the values of the different Cplane in a list of a list called LDTvalue 
#print(int(LDTheader['Mc']/int(LDTheader['Symmetry']))+1)
for j in range(0,int(LDTheader['Mc']/int(LDTheader['Symmetry']))+1):    
    if LDTheader['Symmetry'] == '4':
        for i in range(1,LDTheader['Ng']):
            LDTtemplist.append(float(LDTline[42+LDTheader['Ng']*(j+1)+LDTheader['Mc']+(LDTheader['Ng']-i)]))
        for i in range(0,LDTheader['Ng']-1):
            LDTtemplist.append(float(LDTline[42+LDTheader['Ng']*(j+1)+LDTheader['Mc']+(i)]))
        LDTvalue.append(list(LDTtemplist))
        del LDTtemplist
        LDTtemplist = list()

if LDTheader['Symmetry'] == '4':
    for i in range(1,LDTheader['Ng']):
        LDTtemplist.append(float(LDTline[42+LDTheader['Ng']+LDTheader['Mc']+(LDTheader['Ng']-i)]))
    for i in range(0,LDTheader['Ng']-1):
        LDTtemplist.append(float(LDTline[42+LDTheader['Ng']+LDTheader['Mc']+(i)]))
LDTvalue2 = LDTtemplist
del LDTtemplist
LDTtemplist = list()

class MyPDiagram(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='polar')

        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        #self.axes.hold(False)

        t = arange(-180,180,LDTheader['Dg'])
        t = radians(t)
        self.axes.plot(t, LDTvalue[0], color='r', linewidth=1)
        self.axes.plot(t, LDTvalue[6], color='b', linewidth=1)
        self.axes.set_theta_zero_location("S")
        self.axes.grid(True)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)



class MyCDiagram(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        #self.axes.hold(False)

        x = arange(-180,180,LDTheader['Dg'])
        self.axes.plot(x, LDTvalue[0], color='r', linewidth=1)
        self.axes.plot(x, LDTvalue[6], color='b', linewidth=1)
        self.axes.grid(True)
        #
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)



class MainWindow(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        buttonOK = QPushButton('OK')
        buttonClean = QPushButton('Clean')
        pd_label = QLabel('Polar Diagram')
        pd = MyPDiagram(QWidget(self), width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        cd_label = QLabel('Carthesian Diagram')
        cd = MyCDiagram(QWidget(self), width=5, height=4, dpi=100)

        buttonClean.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClean)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(buttonOK, 1, 0)

        grid.addWidget(buttonClean, 1, 1)

        grid.addWidget(pd_label, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(pd, 3, 0, 5, 1)

        grid.addWidget(cd_label, 2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(cd, 3, 1, 5, 1)
        grid.update()
        self.setLayout(grid) 

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1000, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('W&D LDTcleaner')    



    def handleButtonClean(self):
        #1. Clean the value above 90 degrees
        for j in range(0,int(LDTheader['Mc']/int(LDTheader['Symmetry']))+1): 
            for i in range(180,LDTheader['Ng']-1):
                LDTvalue[j][i] = 0

        #2. Clean when center value is not the max
        for j in range(0,int(LDTheader['Mc']/int(LDTheader['Symmetry']))+1): 
            for i in range(0,LDTheader['Ng']-1):
                if LDTvalue[j][0] < max(LDTvalue[j]):
                    LDTvalue[j][0] = max(LDTvalue[j])



        self.initUI() #-----> This is where I am blocked. I tried to recall initUI()
        print('Cleaned!')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your imports (as in the exact way your import your libraries) is important to run your code. Otherwise anyone you might want to help by running the code will have to try to reconstruct the example first. Also you seem to be using some variables that are not defined in the code example you gave, namely LDTvalue and LDTheader (or at least I didn't catch it). I'll assume they are global since you seem to be using it everywhere (something to review in the future perhaps).

Comment: As for your problem do not call the function initUI since its doing a lot of stuff that does not need change. Create a new function just to redraw the plot. For that check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441906/matplotlib-how-to-refresh-figure-canvas).

Comment: Hello Thank you for your feedback. I know that I should not call back the initUI function, but I tried with another function to refresh only the figures, but it doesn't work...